# Strange strings appear on the left side of the code box（lstlisting evironment）

Tags: listings

First of all, I am sorry for my bad English. I hope that you can understand what I said next.

I want to add a piece of code in my paper, so I chose the lstlisting environment, the code is as follows

```
\begin{lstlisting}
let factory = getFactory();
let redeemingEvent = factory.newEvent('org.essential.medichain.transactions'
,'RedeemedPrescription');
redeemingEvent.recordId = transaction.recordId;
emit (redeemingEvent);
\end{lstlisting}
```

I have added the listings package at the beginning of my tex-file. The compiled result is as shown below：
[image]

The character of frame+number appears at the position where the number of lines should appear. Why is this happening, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that reproduces the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: as most listings environments do not do that, clearly the problem is in code you have not shown, please provide a full example that reproduces the output that you show. Presumably you have some  code adding the text `frame` to `\thelinenumber` or a related command.